# Webpack Middleware Hot Module Replacement with ServiceStack (without MVC)

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, servicestack, hot-module-replacement

When I debug my project in VS Code my NET Core Web App serves the content in wwwroot.

Is there a way when using ServiceStack to also add the Webpack Middleware used by MVC to enable HMR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No all [ServiceStack SPA Templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-single-page-apps) use the npm CLI tooling, not MVCs middleware.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question kind of related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52096652/vue-js-router-history-mode-with-servicestack-routing-fallback-and-api-prefix