# Vue.js router history mode with ServiceStack routing fallback and Api prefix

Tags: vuejs2, servicestack, vue-router

1. Every client side route starts with a hash. How can I enable History Mode in Vue Router without disturbing the api routing?
2. Also I would prefer not to have to start my routes with "/api". Client side routing didnt work with Config.HandlerFactoryPath set to "api". Is there a way to achieve it?

**APPHOST**

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    private BackendSettings _settings;
    private IHostingEnvironment _environment;

    public AppHost(BackendSettings settings, IHostingEnvironment environment) : base("Template.Www", typeof(SurveyService).Assembly)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _environment = environment;

        Routes                
            .Add<GetSurvey>("/api/survey/{id}", "GET");
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        bool isDevelopment = _environment.IsDevelopment();

        Plugins.Add(new TemplatePagesFeature());

        SetConfig(new HostConfig
        {
            AddRedirectParamsToQueryString = true,
            DebugMode = isDevelopment,
        });
    }
}
```

**STARTUP**

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var backendSettings = GetBackendSettings();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseServiceStack(new AppHost(backendSettings, env));
    }

    private BackendSettings GetBackendSettings()
    {
        var settings = new BackendSettings();
        Configuration.GetSection("Backend").Bind(settings);
        return settings;
    }

    private FrontendSettings GetFrontendSettings()
    {
        var settings = new FrontendSettings();
        Configuration.GetSection("Frontend").Bind(settings);
        return settings;
    }
}
```

**REQUEST MODEL**

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo}", Matches = "AcceptsHtml")]
public class Fallback
{
    public string PathInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**VUE ROUTER**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/test',
      component: Test
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/'
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `[FallbackRoute]` is to return the home page on unmatched routes, so if the route is only defined on the client then full page requests will return the home page so the client routes can handle the routing.

It’s not possible to have matching server routes and client routes as client routes need the fallback handler on the server to return the home page which only happens on unmatched requests.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand your answer entirely. As far as I can see I configured the [FallbackRoute] the same way as in the ServiceStack Vue Template. Why does history mode work in that template but not here?

Comment: @glazjoon Have a look at the [vue-spa template which has history mode enabled](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/vue-spa/blob/master/MyApp/src/router.ts#L18)

Comment: I updated my Vue Router.. History mode works now but it's not behaving like a SPA. The bundle is loaded every time I change route. Any help?

Comment: @glazjoon I don’t know what that means but you should be starting from one of the SPA templates where it does behave as an SPA, see live demo at http://vue-spa.web-templates.io

Comment: I mean that a SPA shouldn't refresh on client side navigation.